# c++ - Constructor of class type returns a lvalue?

Tags: c++, lvalue, rvalue

Why does the first line not compile while the second line compiles?

```
float& t = float(10); // initial value of reference to non - const must be an lvalue
string& w = string("gg");
```

Does this imply that the string constructor returns a lvalue?

Comment: g++ 4.8.2 gives a " error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type..." for *each* of these lines.

Comment: This is a good question, which makes me wonder how come there is always someone down-voting / close-voting questions here (and without even leaving a comment explaining why). Some users here should be rightfully deprived of that privilege.

Comment: I guess the second line compiles because you are using MSVC and you did not compile with /W4. Had you compiled with /W4, you should have seen something like "warning C4239: nonstandard extension used".

Comment: @barakmanos It appears that the question has the incorrect assumption that the second line is correct. As the question is currently posed, it is simply invalid, as the answers show. It is not likely to be useful for future readers, which is why (I guess) someone picked the close reason *[…]While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.[…]*.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: IMO, "it is simply invalid, as the answers show" is an oxymoron. If there exists a valid answer, then the question is valid by definition.

Comment: @cpplearner yes you are right. I am wondering if this is something specific to MSVC? Couldn't find any info on it.

Answer (score 3):

Constructor by the definition does not have a return value. What you're trying to perform is making a reference to a temporary value which is not allowed.

Good article to understand both `lvalue` and `rvalue` references is [C++ Rvalue References Explained](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html).

Comment: "What you're trying to perform is making a reference to a temporary value which is not allowed." Yes i agree with this statement. I was just confused why the second line compiles. cpplearner is right. I am using MSVC. Perhaps MSVC has some special properties?

Comment: That's strange, because I get the same error in both cases with gcc and clang: `cannot initialize non-const reference from an rvalue`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are getting is not what you are expecting:

```
float& ref = float(10);
```

What does happen here? `float(10)` creates a temporary float (not bound to anything), it is thus an *rvalue*. Therefore you cannot bind it to a non-const lvalue reference.

```
float const & cref = float(10); // OK!
```

The mechanics involved in this are the same for `std::string`. I am puzzled that you do not get a compiler error on the string example (I do with gcc  5.3.0)

Note that this has nothing to do with a so-called "constructor return value", because constructors have no such thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is because I am using MSVC.